# want to find records which are starting with http and https

Tags: sql, databricks

I unable to get records which are starting with https and http from websites column of my table.
below is the query I am using in databrics.
NOTE: there is extended webadress associated after http:// and https://
pls help

```
SELECT websites
FROM My_table
WHERE array_contains(websites, "https://%");

SELECT websites
FROM run_apr_36.silver_qa_enhanced
WHERE array_contains(websites, "https://");
```

Comment: Not enough details to get an answer: what is your table definition? Based on a data sample for you to share, what is your expected result and what is the actual result you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

array_contains that you are using in your SQL query looks for an exact match in an array, not a partial match.

Use LIKE to find records that begin with “https://”

```
SELECT websites
FROM My_table
WHERE websites LIKE 'https://%';

SELECT websites
FROM run_apr_36.silver_qa_enhanced
WHERE websites LIKE 'https://%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)
but I am getting below error
[DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE] Cannot resolve "websites LIKE https://%" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 1 requires the "STRING" type, however "websites" has the type "ARRAY<STRING>".; line 3, pos 15

Comment: The `websites` column is an array, not a `string` column. @BhushanJadhav can you try `select website from (select explode(websites) as website from websites) where website like 'http://%' or website like 'https://%'`

Comment: @BhushanJadhav I wasn't sure since I couldn't verify, I've now added an answer

Answer (score 0):

The websites column is an array, not a string column. @BhushanJadhav can you try

```
select website from 
(
    select explode(websites) as website 
    from websites
) 
where website like 'http://%' 
   or website like 'https://%'
```